# ¿Qué tengo mal en mi código?

Tags: javascript, nodos

Ayuda por favor, ya me duele la cabeza jaja no se en que parte del código estoy mal, solo necesito encontrar el error que no se donde lo tengo y verlo en el console log, por mas que intento no se donde esta el error, no me marca error en visual studio ni en console de la web

```
class Nodo{
    constructor(dato, next){
        this.dato = dato;
        this.next = next;
    }
}


//Clase para crear la lista
class ListaEnlazada{
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

//Lista enlazada simple
//insertBefore agrega un nodo al principio de la lista

    insertBefore(dato){
        this.head = new Nodo(dato, this.head);
        this.size++;
    }

//insertAfter agrega un nodo al final de la lista 
    insertAfter(dato){
        let newNode = new Nodo(dato);
        
        if(! this.head){
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        else{
            let tail = this.head;
            while(tail.next !==null){
                tail = tail.next;
            }
            tail.next = newNode;
        }
        this.size++;
    }

//insertAt agrega un nodo en una posicion especifica
    insertAt(dato, index){
        if(index < 0 || index > this.size){
            return null;
        }

        const newNode = new Nodo(dato);
        let current = this.head;
        let previous;

        if(index === 0){
            newNode.next = current;
            this.head = newNode;
        }else{
            for(let i=0; i<index; i++){
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            newNode.next = current;
            previous.next = newNode;
        }
        this.size++;
    }
//removeFirst remueve el primer nodo.
//removeLast remueve el ultimo nodo.
//removeData remueve un node con el valor que le pasamos

    removeData(dato){
        let current = this.head;
        let previous = null;

        while(current != null){
            if(current.dato === dato){
                if(!previous){
                    this.head = current.next;
                }
                else{
                    previous.next= current.next;
                }
                this.size--;
                return current.dato;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

//removeFrom remueve un nodo de una posocoon en especifica
    removeFrom(index){
        if(index<0 || index>this.size){
            return null;
        }

        let current = this.head;
        let previous = null;

        if(index === 0){
            this.head = current.next;
        }
        else{
            for(let i=0; i<index; i++){
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        this.size--;
        return current.data;
    }

//removeList remueve toda la lista
    removeList(){
        this.head = null;
    }

//isEmpty retorna un true si la lista esta vacia y un flase si la lista no esta vacia
    isEmpty(){
        if(this.size === 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

//Size retorna el tamaño de la lista
    getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }
//Print muestra los nodos de la lista
    print(){
        let current = this.head;
        while(current){
            console.log(current.dato);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    
}

const LISTA = new ListaEnlazada();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y piensas que alguno va a encontrar el error solo mirando el codigo, error que no sabemos que es, porque no especificas que pasa y que deberia pasar? Asi como esta, no podemos ayudarte... respira... da un paso atras.. aclaranos que pasa y que deberia pasar, y pone el codigo relacionado con eso....

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Recuerda hacer el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Que error te saca? en que línea? A propósito, tu código parece faltarle algo al inicio, parece incompleto.

Comment: No se mucho de nodos, pero ese código que pones no hace nada y por eso no da error. Fíjate que simplemente crear una instancia de la clase en LISTA, pero no ejecutas ningun método después, por lo tanto es normal que no te aparezcan errores.  Por ejemplo, al final de tu código agrega un `console.log(LISTA.getSize())` para ver que te devuelve o si te muestra algun error.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado:

Revisando su código y realizando pruebas, insertando con los metodos insertBefore e insertAfter, probando los métodos de eliminación removeFrom(), removeData() y utilizando el el método print() para mostrar los resultados, encontré errores en 2 métodos:

```js
1)

//insertAfter agrega un nodo al final de la lista 
    insertAfter(dato){
        let newNode = new Nodo(dato,null);//hay que colocar nodo siguiente a null, así deja de mostrar error.
        
        if(this.head == null){
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        else{
            let tail = this.head;
            while(tail.next !==null){
                tail = tail.next;
            }
            tail.next = newNode;
        }
        this.size++;
    }
    
  

2)

//removeFrom remueve un nodo de una posocoon en especifica
    removeFrom(index){
        if(index<0 || index>=this.size){//index debe tener símbolo menor o igual, ya que en caso de indicar el último indice, al utilizar la linea previous.next = current.next; hace referencia al valor next de un elemento null.
            return null;
        }

        let current = this.head;
        let previous = null;

        if(index === 0){
            this.head = current.next;
        }
        else{
            for(let i=0; i<index; i++){
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = current.next;
        }
        this.size--;
        return current.data;
    }
```

Eso es todo lo que encontré con las pruebas realizadas. Espero haber contestado a su pregunta.

Comment: Tratamos de no hacer la tarea de otros.. y sobre todo, si no explican el problema claramente...